# Filtering only 1 column in a df without returning the entire DF in 1 line

Tags: python, pandas

I'm hoping that there is a way i can return a series from df while im filtering it in 1 line.
Is there a way I could return a column from my df after I filter it?
Currently my process is something like this

```
df = df[df['a'] > 0 ]
list = df['a']
```

Comment: use: `df[df['a'] > 0 ]['a']`

Comment: `df.loc[df.a > 0, 'a']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `df.loc` syntax is the preferred way to do this, as @JohnM wrote in his comment, though I find the syntax from @Don'tAccept more readable and scaleable however since it can handle cases like column names with spaces in them. These combine like:

```
df.loc[df['a'] > 0, 'a']
```

Note this is expandable to provide multiple columns, for example if you wanted columns 'a' and 'b' you would do:

```
df.loc[df['a'] > 0, ['a', 'b']]
```

Lastly, you can verify that `df.a` and `df['a']` are the same by checking

```
in: df.a is df['a'] 
out: True
```

The `is` here (as opposed to `==`) means `df.a` and `df['a']` point to the same object in memory, so they are interchangeable.